# Armature's Not Fully Connected to Mesh?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

Back again, I did some repainting the weights on my simple knight here. Previously he didn't have this problem. I had to subtract some weights off the chest which were pulling strangely but the arms seem partially detached from the mesh? I need a picture to describe it, because again, I cannot articulate it properly to let Google answer this question... which is probably ridiculously easy.

[image]

And I attached my blend file for ease.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the weights are painted correctly for the arm?

Comment: @DalekMaker I believe so. The forearm covers forearm area, hands to the hands, and bicep to bicep. No issues on the legs. Just seems to be the arms.

Comment: Your weighs are the problem. They are not painted right. The influence is hard to see, they are just shades of blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the 'Spine' is  also affecting the head and the arms. If you remove the arms and head from this vertex group, it works just fine.

In weight paint mode choose the 'Spine' vertex group. Use the subtract brush to remove the weights from the arms and head. Then test with different poses and adjust the weights where needed.

Here is a screenshot of how it should look like (although some more tweaking is needed :) ):

[image]

Comment: Do I create another vertex group and place the arms and head into that group? When I just remove them from the vertex group window The rig for those bones becomes completely detached from the mesh and does nothing. I also tried unpainting the weights I had given the spine and unparenting the biceps from the spine. Those didn't seem to work either.

Please pardon my complete ignorance.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had originally painted the weights as your second picture looks, but I was having other issues and never went back and changed it. Painting weights is something that has proven a huge hurdle to my learning all of these skills.  Thanks again! I would upvote as well as mark answered but I guess my own ranking is still too low. Cheers!